# Regarding Dependency Injection principle in simple java class

Tags: java

please show me a small example of Dependency Injection principle through simple java class although I have gone and seen through spring , but if I need to explain it in simple java class terms , then can you please show me through a simple example.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either dependency injection or inversion of control, haven't heard of Dependency Inversion yet

Comment: @EranMedan..yeah I have edited it , it is dependency injection dude

Comment: There is a concept Dependency Inversion". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle.  It's not the same as DI or IoC, however.

Comment: @ToddMurray thanks, I learn something new every day...

Answer (score 1):

This article has a very good basic Java example using annotations

http://simplespringtutorial.com/annotations.html

Basics of DI are covered very clearly here with simple Java examples

http://simplespringtutorial.com/di.html

Comment: I was looking in simple java class terms itself..!!

Comment: both links has the most basic Java class examples, not sure what you mean? I don't like the notion of copy pasting a great article if I'm going to paste the entire article. please explain what you are missing?

Answer (score 1):

When using dependency injection, you rely on the container to inject your objects dependencies instead of creating them yourself during execution. For example:

Without using dependency injection I would have to write something like this:

```
public class ATMTransferService {

    private AccountDAO accountDAO;

    public void transfer(Account from, Account to){
    AccountDAO accountDAO = new AccountDAO();
    ...Code that transfers money from one account to another and saves it...
    accountDAO.store();
}
```

Notice that I had to instantiate accountDAO myself, and the responsibility of getting my dependancies was handled by myself.

By using spring or some other framework that allows for DI, I would transfer that responsibility tothe container, by writing something like:

```
<bean id="ATMTransfer" class="com.example.ATMTransferService" >
    <property name="accountDAO" ref="AccDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="AccDAO" class="com.model.AccountDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessFac"
</bean>

<bean id="sessFac" class="..."
     //Dependencies required for the cration fo session factory.
</bean>
```

Now my class would like like this:
public class ATMTransferService {
    private AccountDAO accountDAO;

```
public void transfer(Account from, Account to){
    ...Code that transfers money from one account to another and saves it...
    accountDAO.store();
}
```

In this case, I've ommited the AccountDAO class, but it would have a dependency on a SessionFactory. You could also use a pre-defined constructor instead of using the default constructor by specifying it on the xml configuration.

I hope i haven't simplified it too much, once the benefits of dependency injection are greater than this, you could swap implementation classes by just modifying an xml configuration for starters. You also get a much cleaner code once you remove dependency creation code from your business classes. It is really a great manner to promote interface oriented programming.